# Removing duplicate Values in Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which has duplicate values. It looks like this

```
5   Bernadette  Mendez    F 581916  13  72  68  73  75  84  72  68  77  65  71  70
6   Bobbie  Stanley   M 347045  13  87  89  86  89  88  87  95  87  89  88  NA
7   Casey   Gonzalez  M 732776  13  78  89  99  95  89  85  94  94  98  97  95
8   Cheryl  Silva     F 382579  15  91  91  86  99  89  90  96  88  95  40  NA
9   Cheryl  Silva     F 382579  15  91  91  86  99  89  90  96  88  95  88  90
10  Crystal Armstrong F 815414  16  86  84  86  76  81  87  85  91  81  81  NA
11  Doris   Russell   F 861836  14  89  96  97  78  94  97  86  92  90  99  90
```

I want to remove the duplicate rows based on the fifth column and keep one row out of the duplicates which has the last field as 'NA'.

I am able to remove the duplicate rows by using duplicated method. But I am not able to put a condition on which row to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Sort by last column to put NA values last:

```
df1 <- df1[order(df1[,ncol(df1)], na.last = TRUE), ]
```

Without duplicated 5th column (from last):

```
df1[!duplicated(df1[,5], fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `duplicated` like

```
df[!duplicated(df[, 2:3]), ] # keep first Cheryl
df[!duplicated(df[, 2:3], fromLast = TRUE), ] # keep last Cheryl
```

you could split, apply and re-combine e.g. like:

```
tmp <- split(df, apply(df[, 2:3], 1, paste, collapse = " ")) # split data frame on names
idx <- sapply(tmp, nrow) > 1 # identify duplicates
tmp[idx] <- lapply(tmp[idx], function(df) df[is.na(df[, ncol(df)]), ]) # keep those with NA in last col 
do.call(rbind, tmp) # bind split data frames together again
```

Doesn't look very nice, but gives you more flexibility.