# Removing duplicated values with missing values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I have a Dataframe which contains duplicated rows with missing values. I want to remove duplicated rows while retaining the data of a certain column (e.g. Age in below example). Since one column's value has more weight in model than others I would like to retain that column's data. I tried the methods proposed at [Removing duplicate Values in Dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790169/removing-duplicate-values-in-dataframe-in-r) but my dataframe is large and missing values are spread in more than one column. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
**Name, age, city, edu, phone**
ali, 23, bali, matric, NA
brad, 24, sofia, inter, NA
ali, NA, bali, matric, 786
brad, NA, sofia, inter, 555
ali, 9999999, bali, matric, 444
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
**Name, age, city, edu, phone**
ali, 23, bali, matric, NA
brad, 24, sofia, inter, NA
```

Regards,

[DF with duplicated Missing values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcviC.jpg)

Comment: Please `dput` your data. What is the expected output?

Comment: Please add some expected output to your question. Also, can you show some code that you used to try and solve this?

Comment: Just `order`  and simply remove `duplicated` entries

Comment: They aren't duplicates if they aren't the same.

Comment: @RichScriven I thought OP meant duplicated excluding columns with NAs. Generous assumption to make though I guess

Comment: I don't see why `na.omit` wouldn't work, after changing `9999999` to `NA` (if that's what it is).

Comment: what makes `ali, 23,...` more favorable than `ali, 99999,...` ? does have to do with the value or row order or something else?

Comment: @RichScriven I meant the same as Sotos mentioned
I will build a predictive model and the value 99999999 is unrealistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `dplyr`, `magrittr`. You'll need however to set a threshold for the age parameter which might not guarantee a unique set of rows `age` aside.

```
THRESHOLD <- 100
df %<>% na.omit() %>% filter(age<THRESHOLD)
```

or using `base` as follows

```
THRESHOLD <- 100
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
df <- df[df$age < THRESHOLD,]
```